# Convert Xml Diffgrams to xpath?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmldiff

I am using the Microsoft Xml Diff Path API and it is generating a diffgram like this

```
<xd:node match="2">
    <xd:node match="1">
        <xd:node match="1">
            <xd:node match="2">
                <xd:change match="@randomAttribue">MATCH VALUE</xd:change>
                <xd:node match="1">
                    <xd:change match="1">NEW TEXT</xd:change>
                </xd:node>
```

My question is how do I convert the various "match attributes" to a single flat Xpath position query that i can apply to the original document to get the actual changed node?